# How to use LookupSPGroupMembers in Workflow Custom Activity (SharePoint)

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-2013, custom-activity

I am creating a custom workflow in sharepoint designer 2013 but i have hit a snag where i cant work out a way to check to see if a user belongs to a specific user group.

This has led me to create a custom activity in Visual Studio 2012. There is a built in activity called LookupSPGroupMembers but i can for the life of me work out how to use the output.

The output is of type DyanamicValue, but I cant workout how to iterate through the value to retrieve the users.

HELP!

Answer (score 0):

I found a way, this is complex to explain here, so please check in:

http://raquelalineblog.wordpress.com/2013/05/20/sharepoint-2013-lookupspgroupmembers-workflow-activity/

The result of LookupSPGroupMembers is an array or list of DynamicValues, you have to create the logic to iterate through this list and get the values of each item.

Comment: Can you at leas try to explain the essential parts in yout answer? As it stands this is what is called a "link-only answer" (See [this discussion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92505/172431))